# PHP - problems accessing multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having problems getting the right data out of this multidimensional(?) array that I retrieve when using FirePHP to see what I'm working with:

```
array(
    ['day'] => 'Wed'
    ['is_used'] => 1
    [0] =>
    array(
        ['day'] =>
        'Wed'
        ['title'] =>
        'onsdag denna veckan 2'
        ['content'] =>
        ['price'] =>
    )
    [1] =>
    array(

        ['day'] =>
        'Wed'
        ['title'] =>
        'onsdagslunchen'
        ['content'] =>
        ['price'] =>
        123123
    )
)
```

I want to use the 0, 1 array in the array if that makes any sense...? Or is this array broken?

When I try

```
foreach ($foo as $bar){
    echo $bar
}
```

I'm getting 4 results, day, is_used and the 0, 1 arrays.

Comment: What is the question? You want to use the `0` and `1` items how? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Yes, I want to use the 0 and 1 item, sorry if that wasn't clear enough,

Comment: the thing is that it could be more or less than 2 items..

Comment: Well the array contains 4 elements. It is perfectly fine. And you iterate over the four elements, so where is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is returning the values correctly. It's returning the first children of the `$foo` array, which are:

```
day
is_used
0
1
```

`day` and `is_used` are strings, but because `0` and `1` are arrays, you'll need to cycle through them again to get their values:

```
foreach ($foo as $fooKey=>$bar){
    if(is_array($bar))
        // cycle through the array
        foreach ($bar as $key=>$value)
            // Echo out the string of the array
            echo "$fooKey $key = $value<br />";
        }
    } else {
        // Echo out the string
       echo "$fooKey = $bar<br />";
    }
}
```

That should echo out the following:

```
day = Wed
is_used = 1
0 day = Wed
0 title = onsdag denna veckan 2
0 content =
0 price =
1 day = Wed
1 title = onsdagslunchen
1 content =
1 price = 123123
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
foreach ($my_array as $key=>$val) {
    if (is_numeric($key) {
        // do something with $val (where $val is an array in the example)
    }
}
```